# Site access and parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon. Please tell me why the 403 error is returned. Why is that? I think I'm specifying the correct headings

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0";
        string acceptHeaders = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.AddArgument($"user-agent={userAgent}");
        options.AddArgument($"accept={acceptHeaders}");
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.dns-shop.ru");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains("DNS"));
            Console.WriteLine("Page title: " + driver.Title);
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to gain successful access to the site for further parsing. I tried different header options, but either a 401 or 403 error was returned.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error tipically means that the server understood your request but it is refusing to fullfill it.
That means that you might not have the permission to access the requested res.
Besides that 401 error means that you might have provided invalid credentials.

The website you are trying to reach out is using any kind of Captcha? Because that could be a reason for that 403
plus, if you sending too many requests in a short time the server might block you.

Hope this helps you a lil bit

Comment: There is no captcha, all products are easily opened and displayed through the browser. There is also no authorization or anything else, this is a regular website for household appliances

Comment: I know that the server accepted my request, but why didn't it return a response to me...